# Loading js/css if it is necessary in that page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have more than 50 js+css files which are not actually necessary for all page.i.e:I need a `carousel()` on the `.carousel` class.But The pages which have not `.carousel` class do not need `carousel()` function and `carousel.js` and `carousel.css` file.So they are unnecessary for this page And they costs more `bytes` and `times` to load them.How can i handle this type of situation?

Comment: If you always load jQuery, at DOM Ready event you could do `if ($('.carousel').length > 0) { $.getScript("jquery.carousel.js", ...)... ` then on the success callback you initialize the plugin

Comment: To use less letters in if if ($('.carousel') [0]) {...}

Answer (score 1):

You could use requireJS for this. It allows you to create your javascript modular and only load the modules that you need for that page. http://requirejs.org/

It also supports css, but not completely: http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#css